# Is there any partial order that extends $\delta$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $M = \{(x_n)_{n\ge1} | x_n \in \mathbb Z, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\}$

We define relations $\delta$ and $\sim$ on $M$ as:

$(x_n)_{n\ge1}\ \delta\ (y_n)_{n\ge1} \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, y_n - x_n \in \{0,2^n\}$

$(x_n)_{n\ge1} \sim (y_n)_{n\ge1} \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, 2^n \mid y_n - x_n$

1) Is there any partial order that extends $\delta$? (If yes, find the smallest relation)

2) Is $\sim$ a closed equivalence relation for $\delta$?

3) How can I find a "representative system" ("system of representatives") for $\sim$?

4) How can I show that $M / \sim$ is equipotent with $\mathbb R$?

($M / \sim$ is the system of representatives of $M\ \cup$ equivalence classes of $\sim$)

So far I checked if $\sim$ and $\delta$ are equivalence relations and only $\sim$ is.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far, so we can better understand what your specific problems are.

Comment: I checked if ~ and δ are  equivalence relations and only ~ is, as I said. Also, I have an idea for the system of representatives for this relation ~. x_n = 2^{2+K} with K fixed.

Comment: I have edited the post as you suggested. Not sure what do you mean about $ \mathbb Z$ not being used properly. The given set is telling us that $ x_n \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: I meant not formatting $\Bbb Z$ properly. Other than that, you did *use* it properly. Sorry for my lack of clarity.